# How to open a new window without using a link on the page with WebDriver

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

Without clicking a link on the page I am wondering how I can

- open a new window(not tab) with WebDriver
- take control of that window
- do some actions and change control to the original window.

What I have tried to is run `WebDriver.ExecuteScript("window.open(\"about:blank\", \"_blank\", 'width=300, height=250');");` and then `WebDriver.Manage().Window.Maximize();` but I don't seem to have control of that window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to switch the active window context to the newest window before you can send commands to it like this

```
driver.SwitchTo().Window(driver.WindowHandles.Last());
```

After that the commands should go to that window.